# How to get FFT from audio tag in HTML5

Tags: html, audio, fft

I want to get the FFT data from an `<audio>` tag, but it doesn't work without any syntax error. Looking at the Web Audio API document, I write a sample code, here is my code:

```
<audio id="aud" controls="controls" src="test.mp3"></audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
var audioElement = document.getElementById("aud");
var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
var streamingAudioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
var jsProcessor = audioContext.createJavaScriptNode(4096,1,1);
jsProcessor.onaudioprocess = process;
var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = 2048;

//streaming:AudioSource->jsProcessor->analyser->destination
streamingAudioSource.connect(jsProcessor);
jsProcessor.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
//autoplay
audioElement.play();
function process(event){
    var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData);
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=freqByteData[1];//show data in div
}
</script>
```

My Chrome version is 20.0.1096.1 dev-m and I think it works well. Through process(), I'm trying to write down freqByteData, but it shows 0, and all of them are always 0. 
It must have something wrong of my code, and I want to know how to get frequency data from an audio tag.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that createMediaSourceElement breaks if it's called before window.onload. There is a bug report about this issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112368

There are currently two workarounds:

**Wait the window load event before executing the whole javascript**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  // your code
}, false);
```

or

**Create the MediaElementSource in a setTimeout with 0 delay**

```
setTimeout(function (){
  var streamingAudioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
  var jsProcessor = audioContext.createJavaScriptNode(4096,1,1);
  // The rest of the code
}, 0);
```

Comment: Get it! thank you very much. but if there are many mp3 in audio tag, it doesn't work well when i execute the next().